# Get callback variables in JavaScript-function

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I've downloaded a Javascript file from: https://github.com/cavestri/themoviedb-javascript-library

In my code i have following line:

```
var a= theMovieDb.search.getMovie({"query":"Fight%20Club"}, successCB, errorCB);
```

The method "theMovieDb.search.getMovie(...) should return a JSON-Array but I don't know were to get the "sucessCB" and the "errorCB". Where do I get this two variables?

Comment: You write your own functions and plug them in there.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They're your defined callbacks, you can either define them, or use anonymous functions, like so:

```
theMovieDb.search.getMovie({"query":"Fight%20Club"}, function(data) {
    //success callback
    console.log(data);
}, function(error) {
    //error callback
});
```

Or define:

```
var successCB = function(response) {
    console.log(response);
}

var errorCB = function(error) {
    console.log(error);
}

theMovieDb.search.getMovie({"query":"Fight%20Club"}, successCB, errorCB);
```

Comment: Or define: `function successCB(){ ...`, really the list goes on.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like those should be the names of two functions you define, a callback to be run in case of success, and one for in case of error.